# Drupal: can't add the taxonomy field to Views?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I've prepared a View for my nodes and I've selected which fields to display.

I just realized that there is not the taxonomy field from Content:Taxonomy

There is only Taxonomy:Term category and warning: "The content might be duplicated, use appropriate filters".

Should I use this item ?
What kind of filters should I use ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the "All terms: Taxonomy" field. You can then limit which Vocabularies you would like to include in the field.